# setting background or background image of a div in asp.net webforms

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, webforms, markup

i have a the following code for a following image  path in web project of visual studio solution

```
 Folder1\Images\banner.png'


<div id="placeholder">

</div>
```

and the css to set the background for this is

```
 #placeholder { 
    position:relative;
    width: 40em;
    margin:auto;
    height:4em;
    margin-top: -1em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    background-image:url('../folder1/Images/banner.png');    
    /* background('('../folder1/Images/banner.png') */
    background-size: 40em;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
    clear: right;
    }
```

I also tried with ~ instead of ../ symbol but it doesnt work.

Should i use background-image or background attribute to set the background image of the div. whichever attribute i use i don't get any image in the background.
please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a add a `width` and a `height` of the background image for it to display properly.

So you want something like

```
#placeholder { 
    background-image:url('../folder1/Images/banner.png');    
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: sorry i was just focusing on background attribute. the rest of the attributes have been included now

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my local machine

Comment: Hi Izzy it was something to do with the default position of the css placeholder. it works fine now. Thank you